# How do I change dropwizard's access log format?

Tags: java, logback, dropwizard

I want to output the access logs to console. I also want to log files with the following configuration:

`server:
requestLog:
    appenders:
      - type: file
        currentLogFilename: D:/Log/access.log
        archivedLogFilenamePattern: D:/Log/access-%d.log.gz
        logFormat: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS,Asia/Shanghai} %-6level [%t] %c %msg %n"
      - type: console
        logFormat: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS,Asia/Shanghai} %-6level [%t] %c %msg %n"
template: Hello, %s!
defaultName: Stranger`

I can run my application normally, but the logformat output is not like my configuration in the configuration file. I can rewrite the class using the org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNCSARequestLog's log method, but obviously this is a very bad method. It solves the problems but if I want to upgrade my application I have to modify all of my AbstractNCSARequestlog class, which is very troublesome and messy.

What is another way I can go about this problem?

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible out of the box. If you look in: RequestLogFactory, the build method does not take into account what format you supplied. It uses a hardcoded format for it. If you want your own format in there, you will need to overwrite this class

Comment: I don't want to overwrite any class , how do i solve this problem by modifying some configuration files ?

Comment: As far as I know, you don't. The only other way that may work is to log a custom logevent which knows how to format itself.